# How can I find light fixtures with bases large enough for my box?

Tags: lighting

We just had an electrician add an electrical box over our vanity. It is round with diameter 4.5". We are looking at several vanity lighting options but every single one we like has a baseplate smaller than 4.5" and won't cover the box. Is there an easy way to make this work? I'm not particularly handy. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That is a standard size light box, so most light bases should cover it.  It has been years since I looked, but I do not think it has changed that much, unless you trying to lights from a different country(Europe).

Comment: A link to one of these fixtures might shed some light on the situation.

Comment: @crip, it's a bit oversized, being an old work box. New work boxes don't have the surface flange.

Answer (score 5):

Keep on looking. That's a standard size junction box for old work. I just Googled "vanity lights" and the first dozen I saw would work on this box. Make sure you're measuring things correctly.

Comment: Actually it's a bit oversized, being an old work box. New work boxes don't have the surface flange.

Comment: @isherwood      Good point. How about standard size junction box for old work?

Answer (score 2):

If the lights you are looking at do not fit that box they are probably not UL listed and you do not want to use them anyway.

There are all kinds of plumbing and electrical things on the market that do not meet the standards for most of North America. However the power of the internet allow the unsuspecting to purchase them.